# Getting class not found for schema provider

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to publish a message on kafka topic using avro, getting this exception :-
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/SchemaProvider

Comment: Are you using Maven/Gradle? Can you share your dependencies list?